# Django ElasticSearch DSL DRF aggregations

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, elasticsearch-aggregation

What is the correct approach to adding aggregations to Django ElasticSearch DSL DRF? The codebase contains some empty filter backends

https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf/tree/a2be5842e36a102ad66988f5c74dec984c31c89b/src/django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf/filter_backends/aggregations

Should I create a custom backend or is there a way to add them directly to my viewset?

In particular, I want to calculate the sum of an IntegerField across all results in a particular facet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch has more than one type of aggregations. Simple aggregations in the `django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf` are implemented in the [FacetedSearchFilterBackend](https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf/blob/master/src/django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf/filter_backends/faceted_search.py). [Read the docs](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage_examples.html#faceted-search) or simply run the example project to run experiments.